# Why is telnet command output distorted in OEL 6.8 version

Tags: telnet, oracle-linux

I am wondering why the telnet command output on OEL 6.8 kernel 2.6.39-400.278.2.el6uek.i686 is distorted. The "L" of Login is not displayed and when the username is entered the prompt is not reset correctly. It happens every time I hit Return. Here is an example of the command on this Linux version.

telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Oracle Linux Server release 6.8
Kernel 2.6.39-400.278.2.el6uek.i686 on an i686
ogin:
    Password:

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you should probably be wondering why you are using telnet in the first place...

Comment: I agree with you on this. But the product I am supporting needs this to be supported for older versions, So I was wondering why it is like this on 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the kernel version above has issues. I had to update the kernel version to 2.6.39-400.294.1.el6uek to fix the issue.

telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Oracle Linux Server release 6.8
Kernel 2.6.39-400.294.1.el6uek.i686 on an i686
login: xyz
Password: